# How to prevent a TransformerFactory with feature FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING set true from stripping attributes?

Tags: java, xslt

I have 2 `TransformerFactory` instances: one default, one with secure processing feature set `true`.  Each generates a `Templates` for the same XSL file.  When I apply a transformation to XML data for each, I receive different results.

The output generated from the secure `TransformerFactory` stripped the attributes from my elements.
The console output identified: `SystemId Unknown; Line #xx; Column #yy; "zzzz" attribute is not allowed on the vvvv element!`

**What is going on here, and how do I prevent this?**

I am required to set secure processing to true, going forward.  Note that if I apply the attribute using the `xsl:attribute` tag (`<xsl:attribute name="variable">value</xsl:attribute>`), then it is not ignored by the transformation, however I have many XSL files that are much larger than the sample and changing this would require a massive effort.
There must be a setting to allow for secure processing, but also allow for the strict attributes.

**RESEARCH SECTION**

- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030909/setting-secure-processing-in-transformerfactory-leads-to-problems-in-xsl) unanswered because it got conflated with a focus on Apache-FO instead of the actual problem, which is the secure transformer.
- According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273763/execute-xslt-with-xalan-in-secure-mode-to-create-xhtml-throws-transformerconfigu), this may be an issue with xalan-2.7.1/xalan-2.7.2 library; I will research and update dependencies.

**DATA SECTION**

**Sample Code**

```java
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.xml.transform.Templates;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class XformTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {

            File BASE_FOLDER = new File("C:\\path-to-work-folder\\");
                
            File outFolder = new File(BASE_FOLDER, "out_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            outFolder.mkdirs();

            String xmlData = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(BASE_FOLDER, "data.xml"), Charset.defaultCharset());
            File xslFile = new File(BASE_FOLDER, "format.xsl");
            
            StreamSource dataSource = null;
            StreamSource xslSource = null;
            TransformerFactory factory = null;
            Templates template = null;
            Transformer transformer = null;
            StringWriter writer = null;
            File outFile = null;
            String result = null;
            
            // DEFAULT
            System.out.println("DEFAULT");
            outFile = new File(outFolder, "default.html");
            dataSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlData));
            xslSource = new StreamSource(FileUtils.openInputStream(xslFile));
            factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            template = factory.newTemplates(xslSource);
            transformer = template.newTransformer();
            writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(dataSource, new StreamResult(writer));
            result = writer.toString();
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(outFile, result, Charset.defaultCharset());
            
            // SECURE
            System.out.println("SECURE");
            outFile = new File(outFolder, "secure.html");
            dataSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlData));
            xslSource = new StreamSource(FileUtils.openInputStream(xslFile));
            factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setFeature("http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing", true);
            template = factory.newTemplates(xslSource);
            transformer = template.newTransformer();
            writer = new StringWriter();
            transformer.transform(dataSource, new StreamResult(writer));
            result = writer.toString();
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(outFile, result, Charset.defaultCharset());
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }     
}
```

**Data File "data.xml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<page>
    <record>
    <data>0</data>
    <moredata>888.88</moredata>
    <info>12345</info>
    <name>foo</name>
    </record>
    <Address1>123 ANY STREET</Address1>
    <Address2>SUITE 100</Address2>
    <City>ALBUQUERQUE</City>
    <Country>USA</Country>
    <Fax>1-(888)-686-8281</Fax>
    <Name>MISC 000000AA000CDDE</Name>
    <State>NM</State>
    <Zip>99999-999</Zip>
</page>
```

XSL File **format.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="record" select="page/record"/>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenInputName" value="SpecialValue"/>
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr><td width="100%"><center><span class="Heading">HELP ME FIGURE THIS OUT</span></center><br/>DATA: <xsl:value-of select="page/City"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="100%"><span class="BodyNormal"><b><i>The span should have said BodyNormal 100% and the hidden input should have a name and value of hiddenInputName and SpecialValue respectively</i></b></span></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Default (expected) Output: **"default.html"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
<body>
<form>
<input value="SpecialValue" name="hiddenInputName" type="hidden"/>
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<center>
<span class="Heading">HELP ME FIGURE THIS OUT</span>
</center>
<br/>DATA: ALBUQUERQUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<span class="BodyNormal">
<b>
<i>The span should have said BodyNormal 100% and the hidden input should have a name and value of hiddenInputName and SpecialValue respectively</i>
</b>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Secure (truncated) Output: **"secure.html"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
<body>
<form>
<input/>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<center>
<span>HELP ME FIGURE THIS OUT</span>
</center>
<br/>DATA: ALBUQUERQUE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span>
<b>
<i>The span should have said BodyNormal 100% and the hidden input should have a name and value of hiddenInputName and SpecialValue respectively</i>
</b>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Console Output

```
DEFAULT
SECURE
SystemId Unknown; Line #9; Column #67; "type" attribute is not allowed on the input element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #9; Column #67; "name" attribute is not allowed on the input element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #9; Column #67; "value" attribute is not allowed on the input element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #10; Column #32; "width" attribute is not allowed on the table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #10; Column #32; "border" attribute is not allowed on the table element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #11; Column #22; "width" attribute is not allowed on the td element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #11; Column #52; "class" attribute is not allowed on the span element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #12; Column #22; "width" attribute is not allowed on the td element!
SystemId Unknown; Line #12; Column #47; "class" attribute is not allowed on the span element!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

This is due to xalan-2.7.2.  [Here is the bug in Xalan-J](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2591)

Switching to xalan-2.7.1 solved the problem, but I ended up moving to 2.7.2_3 with an embedded patch, pending a future release.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2_3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```

Note that this is **not** resolved with the Apache xalan-2.7.3 release and there is no servicemix at this time for 2.7.3.